# Bash: ls command displaying recursively, though -R not specified

Tags: bash, ls

I'm having a frustrating, but seemingly simple problem.  I was recently pushing some files to github and now `ls` has started listing directory contents recursively when I use the basic command `ls`.  Though, it only appears to do so in my Google Drive folder. It functions normally when used in directories outside of Google Drive.  I'm not sure if it is connected to something I was doing with `git` or completely unrelated.  I had been working on a github project in my Google Drive when I noticed the issue.

The output of `type ls` in the Google Drive directory and outside of it is:

```
ls is hashed (/bin/ls)
```

Does anyone have any input on how I can get `ls` to function 'normally' again?  I'm not sure how I could've changed its function but it appears I must have. Let me know if there is additional information that would help in understanding the problem.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Check `alias | grep ls`. Do you use a [folder-specific .bashrc or .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/q/915703/340330)?

Comment: @Cyrus `alias | grep ls` didn't produce any results. I am not using a folder-specific .bash_profile

Answer (score 1):

Your `ls` might be [alias](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html)ed (perhaps in your `~/.bashrc`; look inside file that with your editor) by your interactive shell (or it might become a [bash function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html)). Check with `type ls` (using the [`type` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#type)).

Use `\ls` or `/bin/ls` to get the real `ls` program.

If your shell is `bash`, be sure to read the chapter on [*bash startup files*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html).

Try also using [stat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) and/or some other shell (e.g. [`zsh`](http://zsh.org/), `sash`, ...).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  Both `\ls` and `/bin/ls` produced the same recursive results from within Google Drive. The shell is `bash`, I'll check out the link

Comment: What is the output of `type ls`? That should go into your question!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

I'm not sure *why* this was occurring, but the issue seems to be related to having updated a Shiny app through `rsconnect()` in R.  I closed RStudio and now the `ls` command is working properly again in all directories.  I have no idea why this would occur and didn't think that would be related at all.  Thanks for the troubleshooting help!